# Hourly data from a table containing per minute data

Tags: postgresql

I have a table which contains three columns in a PostgreSQL database. The three columns are `timestamp`, `tag` and `value`. In this table data is automatically inserted from log file generated by SCADA server. I need hourly data from this table. (20:00:00, 21:00:00)

```
timestamp       tag value
2019-06-06 06:00:00 x   123
2019-06-06 06:00:00 y   456
2019-06-06 06:01:00 x   123
2019-06-06 06:01:00 y   656
2019-06-06 06:02:00 x   123 
2019-06-06 06:02:00 y   333 
.......
.......
2019-06-06 06:59:00 x   2232
2019-06-06 06:59:00 y   654
2019-06-06 07:00:00 x   5645
2019-06-06 07:00:00 y   54654
```

I want data exactly at 2019-06-06 06:00:00 07:00:00 from this. The table is getting updated every minute hence I cant write it in where.

Desired Output should be like this.

```
timestamp               tag value
2019-06-06 06:00:00     x   123
2019-06-06 06:00:00     y   456
2019-06-06 07:00:00     x   5645
2019-06-06 07:00:00     y   54654
...
.....
......
2019-06-09 07:00:00     x   5645
2019-06-09 07:00:00     y   54654
```

Comment: Share some data and the output you expect. Otherwise it's nearly impossible for anyone to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you only want those rows that were recorded at exactly the full hour.

you can do that with a simple WHERE clause

```
select *
from the_table
where date_trunc('hour', "timestamp") = "timestamp";
```

`date_trunc` "truncates" the timestamp value to the given granularity. So minutes, seconds and milliseconds will be set to zero.

Comment: I want data of different intervals like 5 minutes,10 minutes,15 minutes (Between two time intervals given by user) etc from above mentioned data through web application. How should I write a query for that ?

Answer (score 0):

You can extract the hour part of the timestamp first, then group your result by the hour.

```
SELECT date_part('hour',  timestamp) as hour, STRING_AGG(tag, ','), STRING_AGG(value, ',')
    FROM your_table
    GROUP BY hour;
```

Various [functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/functions-datetime.html) to extract different parts of a timestamp.

[STRING_AGG](http://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-aggregate-functions/postgresql-string_agg-function/) can be used to combine values from different rows.